# Adding Custom columns in React Material-table

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I'm new to MERN, so any help would be appreciated. I'm trying to create a Stocks app.
I have retrieved the data using `axios` and have displayed it in the table using `Material-Table`.

```js
    import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
    import MaterialTable from 'material-table'
    import axios from "axios";
    
    const DataTable = () => {
      const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);
      const columns = [
        {title: 'NAME', field: 'name', width: 200},
        {title: 'SYMBOL', field: 'symbol', width: 200},
        {title: 'MARKET CAP', field: 'market_cap', width: 200},
        {title: 'CURRENT PRICE', field: 'price', width: 200}
      
      ]
      useEffect(() => {
            axios
              .get(
                "https://api.nomics.com/v1/currencies/ticker?key=xyz&interval=1d,30d&convert=USD&per-page=100"
              )
              .then((res) => {
                console.log(res);
                setTableData(res.data);
              })
          }, []);
    
      return (
          <div>
              <div >
          <MaterialTable style={{height: 400, width: '70%', left: '14%', top: 100}}
            data={tableData}
            columns={columns}
            title={"Stock Details Table"}
            options={{
          search: true
          
        }}
            
          />
        </div>
          </div>
        
      )
    }
    
    export default DataTable
```

But now, I want to be able to save the row data of any company that I select into a MongoDB database and should be able to view all the companies that I selected.

My question is, how do I add a separate column that has buttons for each company to enable me to add the row data to my MongoDB database? I don't know how to add custom data along with the data from the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Material-Table [documentation](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/actions), there is a `onClick` action property exist for the `<MaterialTable>` component:

> onClick: This event will be fired when the button is clicked. Parameters are `event` and `row` or `rows`

So, you need to pass a function to `onClick` property.
This function will get the row detail so you can post it to the server with another API call.

```
const handleSelectedRow = (event, row) => {
  // console.log(row) to see the data and choose your require to send with API calling
  axios.post("/saveMySelection", row).then(() => {}).catch(() => {}) // don't forget to use then and catch method with proper actions
}


<MaterialTable style={{height: 400, width: '70%', left: '14%', top: 100}}
  data={tableData}
  columns={columns}
  title={"Stock Details Table"}
  options={{
    search: true      
  }}
  actions={[
    {
      icon: 'save',
      tooltip: 'Save User',
      onClick: (event, rowData) => hadnleSelectedRow
    }
  ]}
/>
```

You can also take a look at the first example of the working version on the documentation link that I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Thank you so much ! if i were to read the data from mongodb 
    app.get('/saveMySelection', (req, res) => {
  
  for (let item of req.query){
    console.log(item.name)
    console.log(item.price)
  }  ...... is this how i would do it ?

Comment: it depends on your implementation of project requirements, I suggest you ask another question (in the new post) with more focus on the issue but the question may lead to being an opinion based question without your efforts and clarification @Leo